# Discovery Service not awake on server startup

Tags: web8, discovery-service, cdaas

I have installed my live and staging services (CDaaS) on the same machine:

Live Discovery + Content + Live Deployer + Context
Staging Discovery + Preview + Staging Deployer

All the services work fine until the server restarts.  When the server restarts the Discovery Services show to be running in the Services snapin but when I try to access localhost:8082/discovery.svc (or 8092 for live) the browser continuously tries to load but never does.
If I restart the service then it's always fine again.
I have tried to start the service Automatic (delayed) but that did not help.  I also fixed the dependencies so that all the services align to the correct discovery.

The log files provide no indication of any issues.

Answer (score 5):

I fixed this by making all the CDaaS services start Automatic (delayed) so I am guessing they all needed the SQL database to be fully up and running before they could start, although that is a guess.  Either way they work fine now.

[image]

I also had to change the dependencies in the Live services because the installService.ps1 is hard coded to make the dependendency of each service set to the default Discovery.  Note, this only applies when you have multiple Discovery Services on the same machine!

[image]

You can see in the screen shot that I updated the dependency of this service to my Live Discovery on line 50 of the service's installService.ps1.